# How to get the url from the request

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urllib2, webapp2

I am building a blog and I am working on a way to export it's contents to json and xml. To get this working, I thought of getting the url of the page whose content I wanted to export from the request headers. But I am doubting whether it would work because googling around has not given me any answers.

I am making it such that when I add .json to the end of my blog url the json is being displayed, so that's why I am looking into getting the url from the request, I even used  os.environ but that did not work.

EDIT: So as per @Timbtron's answer I used the

```
self.request.get['path_url']
```

But it only resulted in a key error.

Sorry I understood that wrong it's supposed to be

```
self.request.path_url
```

Comment: Please note that in my answer I link to a series of attributes not keys.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to get the URL that the user requested while processing that user's request. If so, take a look at the following doc:

[Request data - webapp2](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html#common-request-attributes)

Another strategy to consider is that you could create 3 handlers, one for HTML, XML, and JSON. You could setup routing rules to hit the appropriate handler depending on the "file extension" that the user was requesting.

For example:

- http://example.com/article.html -> HtmlBlogHandler
- http://example.com/article.json -> JsonBlogHandler
- http://example.com/article.xml -> XmlBlogHandler

Just another idea to consider.

Comment: Well I am making a separate XML handler for exporting it to xml, and thanks a lot for that link @Tombatron. So if I understand that right, if I use `self.request.get('url_path')` then I'll get the url that the user wants to parse ?

Comment: When I add the request attribute to the get function self.request.get['path_url'] I am getting a key error.

Comment: 'path_url' isn't a dictionary key, it's an attribute of the request object. `self.request.path_url` should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry for the extremely late response. And I did try that too using `self.request.path_url`, it results in the following [traceback](http://pastebin.com/keJYnz9L). And thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parsing the url_path in your code, you could let the [URI Routing](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html) take care of it for you (borrowing from Tombatron's example):

```
class HtmlBlogHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('This is the HtmlBlogHandler.')

class JsonBlogHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('This is the JsonBlogHandler.')

class XmlBlogHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('This is the XmlBlogHandler.')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    (r'/article.html', HtmlBlogHandler),
    (r'/article.json', JsonBlogHandler),
    (r'/article.xml', XmlBlogHandler),
])
```

You can customize the routes to handle various article IDs and types.

Comment: I am using URI Routing for the particular handlers, the problem is coming when I am trying the access the url that the user requested for parsing to JSON or XML.

Comment: Why not let the routes parse the URL for you?  `(r'/article/json/(\d+)', JsonBlogHandler)` will parse out a number.  Then use `def get(self, article_id)` to get that number.

Comment: Okay, I am sorry but I am not able to understand what you mentioned properly. What you mean to say is that I can get the routes to parse the url for me ?I mean I have to implement a function to parse the the page into json or xml right ? @BrentWashburne . Sorry for my extremely noobish questions. And thanks for all the replies

Comment: That's exactly right.  Each `Route` is a regular expression to parse URLs.  The examples in my answer were copied from here:  http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html